# Scala MatchError while joining a dataframe and a dataset

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have one dataframe and one dataset :

Dataframe 1 :

```
+------------------------------+-----------+
|City_Name                     |Level      |
+------------------------------+------------
|{City -> Paris}               |86         |       
+------------------------------+-----------+
```

Dataset 2 :

```
+-----------------------------------+-----------+
|Country_Details                    |Temperature|
+-----------------------------------+------------
|{City -> Paris, Country -> France} |31         |       
+-----------------------------------+-----------+
```

I am trying to make a join of them by checking if the map in the column "City_Name" is included in the map of the Column "Country_Details".

I am using the following UDF to check the condition :

```
    val mapEqual = udf((col1: Map[String, String], col2: Map[String, String]) => {
        if (col2.nonEmpty){
            col2.toSet subsetOf col1.toSet
        } else {
            true
        }
    })
```

And I am making the join this way :

```
dataset2.join(dataframe1 , mapEqual(dataset2("Country_Details"), dataframe1("City_Name"), "leftanti")
```

However, I get such error :

```
terminated with error scala.MatchError: UDF(Country_Details#528) AS City_Name#552 (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias)
```

Has anyone previously got the same error ?
I am using Spark version 3.0.2 and SQLContext, with scala language.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues here, the first one is that when you're calling your function, you're passing one extra parameter `leftanti` (you meant to pass it to `join` function, but you passed it to the udf instead).
The second one is that the udf logic won't work as expected, I suggest you use this:

```scala
val mapContains = udf { (col1: Map[String, String], col2: Map[String, String]) => 
  col2.keys.forall { key => 
    col1.get(key).exists(_ eq col2(key))
  }
}
```

Result:

```scala
scala> ds.join(df1 , mapContains(ds("Country_Details"), df1("City_Name")), "leftanti").show(false)
+----------------------------------+-----------+
|Country_Details                   |Temperature|
+----------------------------------+-----------+
|{City -> Paris, Country -> France}|31         |
+----------------------------------+-----------+
```